# SQL Server - select pairs of available stock options

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL, I have a table that stores pairs of product options that have been requested by customers.  This table looks like this:

```
**OptionID,  CustomerID, ProductID**
1,          15,          338
2 ,         15,          161
3,          15,          777          
4,         22,          999
5,          22,          614
6,         22,          7411
7,          22,          2301
8,          22,          2254
```

I want to end up with a list of available product pairs, when checking the stock data, such as:

```
**CustomerID, Product 1, Product2**
   15     ,    338     , 298
   15      ,   161     , 241
```

The stock data looks like this:

```
**StockData**
298
338
161
91
241
96
99
102
104
```

Comment: What is the criteria for pairing the products? 338 and 298 are matched and 161 and 241 are matched. They both use CustomerID of 15 but why are those in particular paired with eachother?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just used that as an example of the output.  The criteria is that for customerID 15, I need to check all the options they have requested, if all are in stock then return all pairs of products, if they are not all in stock, just to return the pairs of products that are in stock

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is every combination of 2 product options in stock per customer, then a selfjoin like this should work:

```
select p1.customerID, p1.productID product1, product2.productID product2
from options p1 
join options p2 on p2.customerID=p1.customerID
and p1.productID<p2.productID
where p1.productID in (select productID from stock)
and p2.productID in (select productID from stock)
```

if you'd wanted the first available pair of products, giving priority to the option number then you can do this:

```
;with productpairs as
(
    select p1.customerID, p1.productID product1, product2.productID product2,
    p1.optionID+p2.optionID priority
    from options p1 
    join options p2 on p2.customerID=p1.customerID
    and p1.productID<p2.productID
),
orderedpairs as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY priority) AS rn 
    from productpairs
)
select customerID, product1, product2
from oderedpairs 
where rn=1
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this method